# Manually set TouchOpacity's opacity

Tags: javascript, react-native

Basically I want to be able to adjust my `TouchOpacity` components opacity at will.

Here is my code

```
<TouchableOpacity
    className='Calculator'
    style={
      [
        styles.container,
        {
          transform:[
            {translateX:this.props.anim.x}
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
    onPress={this.hideKeyboard}
    activeOpacity={1}
  >
    <AmountInput />

  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Just to give some context:
`AmountInput` is a basic text input box.

I am using `TouchableOpacity` to hide the keyboard when it is pressed. However I do not want it to change opacity on press, I tried using `TouchableWithoutFeedback` but it's `onPress` event would not work properly with `TextInput`.

Since I am not using `TouchOpacity` for it's intended purpose (changing opacity on touch) I have `activeOpacity` set to `1`. This is overriding the style, but if I get rid of it, than the input box changes opacity when I touch it's container!

Anyone know a way around this? I have an `opacity` variable being passed down through props.

**Edit:**
Here is some code using `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    className='Calculator'
    style={
      [
        styles.container,
        {
          opacity:1,
          backgroundColor:'red',
          transform:[
            {translateX:this.props.anim.x}
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
    onPress={this.hideKeyboard}
  >
    <AmountInput />

  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

But for some reason all of the properties I define in the tag seem to have no effect, I set the `backgroundColor` style to `red` and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution while using `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.
It seems you need to wrap it's children in a `View` tag... even if there is only one, even though the documentation states:

> TouchableWithoutFeedback supports only one child. If you wish to have several child components, wrap them in a View.

And also I am still not able to apply any styles to the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` tag, I had to put them all the `View` child.

here's my updated code:

```
render() {
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback className='Calculator' onPressIn={this.hideKeyboard}>
    <View style={
      [
        styles.container,
        {
          opacity:this.props.anim.opacity,
          transform:[
            {translateX:this.props.anim.x}
          ],
        }
      ]
    }>
      <AmountInput />
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

}

I have been running into a lot of confusion and contradictions with the React-Native documentation. It is such a great tool! The documentation should be more clear and friendly to new react developers.